# Why can't my javascript see which html option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I've got an html select -

```
<select name="startDay" id="startDay">
    <option value=​"01">​Sun 1​</option>​
    <option value=​"02">​Mon 2​</option>​
    <option value=​"03">​Tue 3​</option>​
    <option value=​"04">​Wed 4​</option>​
    <option value=​"05">​Thu 5​</option>​
    <option value=​"06">​Fri 6​</option>​
    <option value=​"07">​Sat 7​</option>​
    <option value=​"08" selected>​Sun 8​</option>​
    <option value=​"09">​Mon 9​</option>​
    <option value=​"10">​Tue 10​</option>​
    <option value=​"11">​Wed 11​</option>​
    <option value=​"12">​Thu 12​</option>​
    <option value=​"13">​Fri 13​</option>​
    <option value=​"14">​Sat 14​</option>​
    <option value=​"15">​Sun 15​</option>​
    <option value=​"16">​Mon 16​</option>​
    <option value=​"17">​Tue 17​</option>​
    <option value=​"18">​Wed 18​</option>​
    <option value=​"19">​Thu 19​</option>​
    <option value=​"20">​Fri 20​</option>​
    <option value=​"21">​Sat 21​</option>​
    <option value=​"22">​Sun 22​</option>​
    <option value=​"23">​Mon 23​</option>​
    <option value=​"24">​Tue 24​</option>​
    <option value=​"25">​Wed 25​</option>​
    <option value=​"26">​Thu 26​</option>​
    <option value=​"27">​Fri 27​</option>​
    <option value=​"28">​Sat 28​</option>​
</select>
```

When I use this code on jsbin I can identify the selected option with jQuery -

```
$('#startDay').val()
```

But on the site I'm working on, http://test.mapov.com/?d=london. The same code fails -

```
> $('#startDay').val()
> null
```

I can't get anything with pure js either -

```
> document.getElementById('startDay').options.selectedIndex
> -1
```

I've checked that there's no other element with that ID on the page. And I cut and paste the html into pasteBin (http://jsbin.com/bivudinagu/1/edit?html,js,console). I just can't make any sense of what's going on here.

This is from my chrome console -

```
> document.getElementById('startDay').options[7]
> <option value=​"08" selected>​Sun 8​</option>​
> document.getElementById('startDay').options[7].selected
> false
```

??!?

Comment: Are you able to produce a minimum example where it isn't working? I'm not wading through that site.

Comment: Works for me on Chrome. What browser are you getting this problem in?

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics I'm afraid, I haven't managed to yet.

Comment: @Hanlet - chrome. looks like it's intermittent too :(

Comment: Instead of `<option selected="selected">...</option>` try `<option selected>...</option>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. Jquery allows you to set an invalid value with `$('#el').val('non-existent-option')`, without throwing an error or updating the option elements to remove the existing `selected` attribute. I was calling

```
$('#startDay').val(8)
```

Somewhere else in the code. There wasn't an `<option>` with this value (the correct value was a string `'08'`). This wasn't giving off any error's and I couldn't see any evidence of it updating the dom -

```
>  document.getElementById('startDay').options[7]
>  <option value=​"08" selected>​Sun 8​</option>​
```

It was however leaving `$('#startDay').val()` returning `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, you have to set an id to your `select`,

```
<select id="startDay">
```

Then you can get the value of the selected option as:

```
$('#startDay option:selected').val()
```

```js
$(function(){
    document.write($('#startDay option:selected').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="startDay">
    <option value="01">Sun 1</option>
    <option value="02">Mon 2</option>
    <option value="08" selected>Sun 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Christos - gives me 'undefined'

Comment: @AidanEwen you welcome. Please, add an id to your select element and let me know. Thanks

Comment: `$('#startDay').val()` will already get the value for you; you _do not_ need to select the options in the selector string.

Comment: Sorry Christos, my bad, the id is there on my site, and and all other code (I just missed it off the first edit of my post - I've updated it now)

Comment: @AidanEwen not a problem at all dude. Please run my code snippet.

Comment: Thanks Christos - it's pretty much the same as the pastebin I included in the question (but a bit more succinct). The problem is that it doesn't work on my site.

Comment: @Have you added the jquery? Sometimes we may forget to do so.

Comment: @Christos I've added jQuery (2.1.3 I think)

Comment: I think it might be caused by the javascript that builds the selects somehow. I'm going to go through some of that code so see if I can find a culprit. Thanks for your help anyway (+1 from me).

Comment: @AidanEwen It's a bit odd. You welcome. One thing I would do. It would to run this js code in the console, having loaded my page. I think that may show you what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here in your question, and in your pastebin, you have

```
<option value="08" selected>8</option>
```

However, on your actual page on test.mapov.com you have

```
<option selected="selected" value="08">8</option>
```

(viewing page source and inspecting the DOM element both showed this)

In my javascript console in Chrome on your actual site I get the following

```
> $("#startDay").val();
null
> $("#startDay option:selected").val();
undefined
```

If I tamper with the DOM and change `selected="selected"` into just `selected`, then I get

```
> $("#startDay").val();
"08"
> $("#startDay option:selected").val();
"08"
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen - I found the problem.  +1 from me any - I did try updating the attribute as you suggested - that looks to be the correct syntax now.